# How to use PayPal mobile sdk without Braintree

Tags: android, ios, paypal, braintree

The merchant asks me to switch from Braintree to PayPal Pro Flow because of requirement big capital or sales. PayPal [docs](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-get-started-with-paypal-payflow-sdks-for-mobile-integration-ts1976) points to the GitHub SDKs repositories [iOS](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK), [Android](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK), which says those SDKs deprecated and have to use Braintree SDKS

`Important: PayPal Mobile SDKs are Deprecated. The APIs powering them will remain operational long enough for merchants to migrate, but the SDKs themselves will no longer be updated. Please use Braintree Direct in supported countries. In other countries, use Express Checkout and choose the Braintree SDK integration option.`

So I'm confused. Is it possible to integrate PayPal payments to the mobile app without Braintree account?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Mohammad from the PayPal support response, there is no SDK for PayPal, you have to use their rest API.

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any clear tutorial or example available any where?

Comment: not sure, there are definitely official docs, but I can't really suggest anything right now.

Comment: is there any solution ?